# Debugging OpenCL on CPU

Tags: opencl, opencl-c, opencl.net

I'm trying to debug OpenCL kernels on CPU target, following this [guide](https://software.intel.com/en-us/openclsdk-devguide-2019-enabling-debugging-in-opencl-runtime) without success.
The kernel builds, app runs, but the breakpoints are not hit.
There is a statement "The Debugger requires setting the global ID of the work-item to debug before the debugging session starts.", but no information on where to set or how the global ID.
Anybody has a working boilerplate project for this or suggestions? thanks!

Comment: Update, after desparation, I tried VS 2015 + older Opencl SDK from intel and that actually adds a "Code builder" menu to the Visual Studio. So I was missing that part in the VS2017 install. However, problem persists, I set the global ID of interest, breakpoint gets not hit.

Answer (score 1):

Try to debug with Oclgrind
https://github.com/jrprice/Oclgrind
https://github.com/jrprice/Oclgrind/wiki
example: Oclgrind -i ./appl

Comment: Will try, really thought of an integrated solution, but this is better than nothing, thank you.